# Selenium Framework using statics

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing a Selenium framework that should be really easy for a tester with relatively little Java knowledge to use and write tests for. In order to keep the framework as user friendly as possible, I've noticed that I am writing a lot of statics so that the tester doesn't have to instantiate the page objects and methods every time. This of course goes against the principles of OOP. Before I get in too deep with this I'd like to see if there are viable alternatives to my approach. I'm including below the login page class that instantiates a webdriver Singleton, has a username/password field, and a login button. There are 2 tests for this page that are run using TestNG. All code to follow:

**LoginPage.java**

```
public class LoginPage {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    private static String username_selector = "username";
    private static String password_selector = "password";
    private static String login_button_selector = "#loginbutton > input";
    private static String fail_message_selector = "error";


    public static void goTo(String environment_url){
        driver = Driver.getDriver();
        driver.get(environment_url);
    }

    public static void loginAs(String username, String password){
        WebElement user = driver.findElement(By.name(username_selector));
        user.clear();
        user.sendKeys(username);
        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.name(password_selector));
        pass.clear();
        pass.sendKeys(password);
        WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(login_button_selector));
        loginBtn.click();
    }

    public static boolean loginErrorDisplayed(){
        WebElement failMessageContainer = driver.findElement(By.className(fail_message_selector));
            if(failMessageContainer.isDisplayed()){
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
    }

    public static String getLoginErrorMessage(){
        WebElement failMessageContainer = driver.findElement(By.className(fail_message_selector));
        String failMessage = failMessageContainer.getText();
        return failMessage;
    }

}
```

**Driver.java**

```
public class Driver {
    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        if(driver == null){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        return driver; 
    }

    public static void killDriver(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**LoginTest.java**

```
public class LoginTest {

@Test(priority = 0)
public void loginfail() {
    LoginPage.goTo("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login");
    LoginPage.loginAs("wrong username", "wrongpassword");
    boolean didLoginFail = LoginPage.loginErrorDisplayed();
    Assert.assertTrue(didLoginFail == true, "Bad login was successful");
    if (didLoginFail){
        LoginPage.getLoginErrorMessage();
    }
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void loginsuccess() {
    LoginPage.loginAs("correct_username", "correctpass");
    boolean didLoginFail = LoginPage.loginErrorDisplayed();
    Assert.assertTrue(didLoginFail == false, "Valid Login was unsuccessful");
}

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer for your question but this will help you to create perfect selenium framework.

I would like to suggest you to create a AbstractTestPage.java having common APIs such as goTo() API. All your pages such as LoginPage.java should extend AbstractTestPage.java for code reusability.

For example :

```
public abstract class AbstractTestPage {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void goTo(String environment_url){
        driver = Driver.getDriver();
        driver.get(environment_url);
    }

}

public class LoginPage extends AbstractTestPage {

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```